# Get 502 Bad Gateway with new Helm charts for Nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

If I install Nginx in my Kubernetes cluster (version 1.20) like this:

```
$ helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
$ helm install --set controller.service.type=NodePort nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx
```

then my web application works fine.

But, if I install Nginx like this (from newest repo):

```
$ helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
$ helm install --set controller.service.type=NodePort nginx-ingress nginx-stable/nginx-ingress --namespace ingress-nginx --version=0.6.0
```

the my web application gets this error message:

502 Bad Gateway

The Nginx version is the same in both cases: 1.19.1

This is my Ingress definition (same used in both scenarios):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: homeautomationweb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"  # To avoid 502 Bad Gateway when using Azure AD authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - homeautomation.webinnovation.no
    secretName: homeautomation-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: homeautomation.webinnovation.no
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: homeautomationweb
          servicePort: 80
```

As you see, I'm using this annotation to avoid the "502 Gateway" that will occur by default:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "16k"
```

But, it seems that this annotation doesn't work when I install Nginx from the "https://helm.nginx.com/stable" repo.

I also observe these differences in the running pods between installing from the different repos:

From the https://charts.helm.sh/stable repo (web app working):

```
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-controller-779b546dd5-6mt4v       0/1     Running   0          3s
nginx-ingress-default-backend-c5449fb44-5gk2x   0/1     Running   0          3s
```

From the https://helm.nginx.com/stable repo (web app gets 502 Bad Gateway):

```
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-684b84ff8b-c7nm2   1/1     Running   0          13m
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to get this to work when installing Nginx from the new official Helm repo?

Comment: I generally use this: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/charts/ingress-nginx
to install the nginx ingress. Don't recognise the new one which you posted.

Comment: @rock'nrolla The new repo I'm referring to is from the official Nginx documentation https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-helm/

Comment: @rock'nrolla Installing Nginx from the Helm repo you mentioned (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx) works fine. It also seems to work without specifying the "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size" annotation, which I don't quite understand as I always have had to specify this to avoid the "502 Bad Gateway" error. I'm still puzzled on how this works.

Comment: I personally have never had to add this annotation to avoid getting 502. Though I've found somewhat similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58943111/nginx-ingress-returns-502-after-post-with-redirect
It's kinda strange in your case as the helm chart which I use has a default `proxy-buffer-size` of 4k. If accessing your ingress host threw an 502 error earlier, because of `proxy-buffer-size`, it should still throw the error. This chart does nothing to solve that.